# upgrade gwt 1.7 to gwt 2.5

Tags: gwt, upgrade

Our project uses gwt 1.7 and jdk 1.5.0_13.
We need to add support for IE9 and above.
For that, we need to upgrade gwt to latest version (2.5) and, therefore, upgrade jdk as well.
While doing so, we are getting errors related to missing source codes in gwt jars (e.g. TimeOutException source code not found).
We have simply replaced the gwt 1.7 jars with latest ones. What else do we need to change?
Is there any guide explaining the migration procedure for gwt?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there isn't any detailed guide explaining the migration. In the documentation project you have only a brief [list of features and breaking changes](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_0_0) for each version, it is very useful though.

You have many posts with the experience of users migrating from 1.7 to 2.0, but almost  very old since 2.0 was released some years ago. There is very little info for migrations from 1.7 to the the last 2.5.

Said that, the main problem you will deal with is the change in the tools for dev and debug, so I recommend first to get used with these tools. Then you have to fix each single 'red' mark in your IDE project. Then you should look for 'yellow' marks in order to avoid using deprecated classes/methods. Finally you could consider replacing some code of your project with new features in 2.x like cell-widgets, layout-panels, etc, see the [showcase](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCheckBox).

The process will be tedious, but it is worth to have your project using last releases if you plan to maintain the application in the future.

BTW, there are [plans to remove](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Google-Web-Toolkit/Ll0W3Ui1CAI) support for IE6, IE8 and even IE9 in future versions of GWT, in order to improve and modernize gwt and to support new html5 features. It will be gradual though: [Solutions for people needing IE7/IE8 support in future GWT releases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110616/solutions-for-people-needing-ie7-ie8-support-in-future-gwt-releases/19111688#19111688)

Answer (score 0):

I updated from 2.2 -2.5 yesterday and had 2 errors I had to overcome.

Jar file was for 2.2- I deleted it, switched to non GWT toolkit, and switched back. This updated(created) to correct jar.

source code problem- for some reason the run config was not transferred correctly. Since i had used a new workspace when updating i copied over the old path to the new workspace. (this was located under: Debug config--> Arguments--> Program arguments

Hope this helps :)